# Convert single zone cluster to regional cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How do I convert a single zone GKE cluster to a regional cluster? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the note [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster) after you create a single zone cluster, you cannot change it from zonal to regional.